# Why cannot I not create an object like this in Python?

Tags: python

Question about objects in python. I have created the following object....

```
class http(object):
    def __init__(self):
         self._resource = None
         self._response = None

    @property
    def resource(self):
        return self._resource

    @resource.setter
    def resource(self, value):
        self._resource = "http://127.0.0.1:8000/%s" % value


     def get(self, resource=None):
        self.resource = resource
        self._response = requests.get(self.resource)
        return self._response
```

Init does not need anything at this stage so I was hoping I could create the object like this....

```
content = http.get("users/")
```

but it won't let me do this, instead I have to pass use the syntax http() but pass nothing...

```
content = http().get("users/")
```

which seems silly if I don't pass anything to `__init__`. I'm wondering how the a Python package like [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) achieves the following syntax....

```
requests.get('https://api.github.com/user')
```

without doing this...

```
requests().get('https://api.github.com/user')
```

why, what does `requests` package do different?

Comment: There is no object to call `get()` on until you have used the *constructor* `http()`.

Comment: @OllieFord so how does requests do it: http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/

Comment: There doesn't seem like much point to making this a class; it has one in attribute and one out attribute, just make it a function.

Comment: @jonrsharpe its just an example to help illustrate the question but I understand there is not a lot of point.

Comment: if you check out the source you will get your answer https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests

Comment: Well in general, if you have a method you *can* call without needing instance attributes, make it a static or class method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Requests defines some extra methods that create an instance of Requests.request behind the scenes.  You can do the same thing for your http class.

```
class http(object):
    def get(self, resource=None):
        self.resource = resource
        self._response = requests.get(self.resource)
        return self._response

def get(resource=None):
    temp_instance = http()
    return temp_instance.get(resource)
```